# Proxy server timeout

Tags: java, ajax, file, spring-mvc, download

I'm making a REST call via frontend to download a file. At backend I'm creating a file and giving it a response.It works fine locally. But when I try to run front end and back end at two different system I'm getting proxy timeout error because the file download request it taking time at backend and probably my proxy server at frontend is giving me timeout. I can not make an Ajax call because of security reasons. Can anybody tell me a possible solution for this?

Comment: Check logs on your frontend server and try identify where the error is coming from. It might be as simple as increasing default timeout on your proxy server, but without investigation you can only guess.

Comment: @sevatitov Thanks I will try this. But can I simulate an ajax like call on fontend to download the file? So that at least it can track request? or send a beacon every 30 second to keep my request alive?

Comment: I usually use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for do quick API calls.